# How do I prevent an attachment to be deleted after resetting the form fields including the trix-editor's contents?

Tags: vue.js, trix, vue-trix

How do I prevent an attachment / image to be deleted  in the storage directory inside the `trix-editor` after resetting the contents inside the `trix-editor`, since after submitting the form inluding the trix-editor. I would reset all the fields and clear the fields in the form.. and after resetting it, I found out that the attachment that I have stored inside the default storage disk is now deleted.

this is how I handle the removal of the attachment

```js
    let url = file.attachment.attachment.attributes.values.url.split("/").pop();
    console.log(url);
    axios.delete(this.remove_attachment_endpoint + `${url}`).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use localstorage then put the value of image name.
then you can attach the file name with localstorage get item. if you want you can remove item after resetting fields .

```
 handleAttachmentChanges: (event) =>{
               let file = event.attachment.file.name;
               localStorage.setItem('file-rich', file);
              console.log(file);
              console.log(event);
              
            }
```

Comment: this is a great one let me try it .

Comment: Bro, can I contact you via email, I want u to help me on a speicific thing concerning trix